# Looking for language database and codes

Tags: multilingual

I am looking for a table of language names and codes like the ISO 639-1 set: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You'll want [ISO 639-3](http://www-01.sil.org/iso639-3/download.asp) if you want the up-to-date list.

Comment: Alright thanks, now I noticed that the table is entirely built using English characters, do they exist in their native languages? This is to allow people to choose their language, and if it is in their own language vs English I think that would make more sense.

Comment: @razass: Regarding the native lanugages see my answer.

Comment: @pvledoux: And yet Google was still perfectly capable of finding it.

Answer (score 0):

Enhancing Obalix answer, I have created a bash script that will take a UTF-8 CSV file and insert it into a database. 
Note that the file provided by Obalix is in UTF-16 NOT UTF-8. The below script checks for its encoding and advises user on how to convert it.

Of course you will need to modify the insert statement according to your schema.

```
#!/bin/bash
USAGE="Usage: $0 <csv-file>"
if [ $# -lt 1 ]
then
  echo $USAGE
  exit 1
fi

csv=$1

if [ ! -f $csv ]; then
  echo "$csv: No such file"
  exit 1
fi

file $csv | grep -q UTF-8
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
  echo $csv: must be in UTF-8 format, use the following command to fix this:
  echo "cat $csv | iconv -f UTF-16 -t UTF-8 | tr -d \"\r\" > utf8-$csv"
  exit 1
fi

mysql=<PATH/TO/mysql/BINARY>
db=<DATABASE_NAME>
user=<USERNAME>
pass=<PASSWORD>
sql=insert-all-langs.sql
echo "-- Inserting all languages generated on `date`" > $sql

printf "Processing CSV file..."

# prepend _ to all lines so that no line starts by whitespace
sed 's/.*/_&/' $csv | while read l; do
  iso6391=`echo "$l" | cut -f4`
  name=`echo -e "$l" | cut -f3 | tr -d "\"" | sed 's/'\''/\\\\'\''/g'`

  echo $iso6391:$name
  # insert ignore supresses errors for duplicate locales (row still not inserted) 
  echo "insert ignore into languages (name, locale, rtl, created_at, updated_at) values ('$name', '$iso6391', 0, now(), now());" >> $sql
done

echo Done

printf "Executing SQL..."
cat $sql | $mysql -u$user -p$pass $db
echo Done
```